# Does the Bootstraperization of my site obviate the viewport declaration?

Tags: asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap, viewport, fluid-layout

I Bootstraperized my asp.net Razor 2 website by implementing what Dan recommended here: [Where should I bootstraperize my web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493807/where-should-i-bootstraperize-my-web-site)

In my _SiteLayout.cshtml file, I had this line that was added by default:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

I don't know if that cooperates with the Bootstraperization I've done, contends with it, or is simply now moot/obviated by the Bootstrap code.

I commented it out and there is no obvious difference, but I'm wondering if my brief sanity check diesbezueglich holds water. Is there any reason to strip it out? Leave it in? Does it [not] matter?

On a related note, should I remove or comment out css in Site.css such as:

```
/* content */
article {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}
```

IOW, will these style rules interfere with the workings of Bootstrap? I want to avoid a tug-of-war between asp.net's baked-in assistance and Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewport meta information is only used for mobile devices, for the zooming and scaling. It concerns the responsive design.

It's not obvious in the current documentation, but here is the explanation from the next version :

> To ensure proper rendering and touch zooming, add the viewport meta tag to your `<head>`.
>
> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

([source](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/184018837b07c216d8667003ac0bd9958eb07cee/docs/css.html#L28))

You can read more about this on the MDN : [Viewport meta tag (developer.mozilla.org)](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: I reckon more and more visitors of my site will be on mobile devices while in the Browseway (while browsing, that is). So "used for mobile devices" is very important to me. Designing for "Mobile First" makes sense for general-public-targeted websites, in most cases, at least. So the question is, does this "zooming and scaling" interfere with, cooperate with, or simply disinterestedly coexist with what Bootstrap does?

Comment: @ClayShannon Keep it simple : Bootstrap responsive design needs this tag.

Comment: Thanks; that's what I'm trying to do: simple as a pimple on Dudley Doright's dimple.